# git fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed

Tags: git, push

I am using git and am trying to push from development to integration but when I press enter I get this message:

```
Counting objects: 36, done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (31/31), done.
fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 269094203 bytes)
error: failed to push some refs to 'File path to integration goes here'
```

I have tried multiple ways to solve it but with the same outcome. such as,

```
[core]
  packedGitLimit = 256m
  packedGitWindowSize = 256m

[pack]
  deltaCacheSize = 256m
  packSizeLimit = 256m
  windowMemory = 256m`
```

---

```
export MALLOCTYPE=3.1
export MALLOCOPTIONS=multiheap
export MALLOC_TRIM_THRESHOLD_=-1
export MALLOC_MMAP_MAX_=0
```

Right now I am at a loss and don't know what to do. So any help will be appreciated!

If it helps the version of git that I am using is 2.10.2

Comment: What is the size of your repo (`du -sh .git`)? How much RAM do you have? How much does Git use before it crashes (use `top` to see it for example)? Essentially, either you have a repo too big for your machine or you just hit a bug in Git (it happens rarely, but it does happen)...

Comment: @MatthieuMoy The size of my repo is 202976 kilobytes. I have 8Gbs of RAM. How do I check your last question in git? Also,I was not able to use `du -sh .git` because it said du was an illegal option so I used `git count-objects -v` don't know if it makes a difference but hope it helps

Comment: It does not seem to be compressing issue as it has written "done". Next it should write objects but usually it does not take much memory. Do you have some big files? Are you pushing one commit or several?

Comment: What remote are you `git push`-ing to, and what is the URL for that remote? (I suspect it translates to a path on your local file system and that the error occurs when working in the repository that exists at that path.)

Comment: `git count-objects -v` doesn't seem to give the size of pack files. Your repo is probably bigger than what you said.

Comment: @max630 Sorry for the late reply this issue is happening at work and I only work Tuesdays and Thursdays. As for your question I am only pushing one commit

Comment: @torek Here is the path that I am trying to push to: /usr/local/zendsvr6/var/apps/https/integration/_docroot_/MN

Comment: @MatthieuMoy Is there an alternative way to get the size of the repository?

Comment: OK, so it is in fact a locally-available file system. As @max630 said the failure occurs after the message "done", implying that it's already compressed the pack-to-send. The issue is that now your Git acts as the "other side" of the transaction: your Git starts a new Git (let's call this G2, your Git is G1) that tries to "download" the pack G1 made. G2 runs in the `/usr/local/.../MN` directory. G2 is the one failing to allocate 269 MB. You could try to convince G2 to use less memory by configuring the G2 repo similarly to your G1 repo (`core.packSizeLimit` and so on).

Comment: @torek Sorry I didn't give you where I am pushing it from it is: `Z:\usr\local\zendsvr6\var\apps\https\lcamacho\_docroot_\MN` and pushing to `Z:\usr\local\zendsvr6\var\apps\https\integration\_docroot_\MN` ... I have tried what you said to do but I am still getting the same problem

Comment: Use whatever command or graphical tool you normally use to get the size of a directory. I already cited `du` which works on Unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker of mine said to just rename the folder MN to MN.old and clone a new MN from where I was pushing it to (`Z:\usr\local\zendsvr6\var\apps\https\integration\_docroot_\M‌​N`).

Once I did that I added the changes that I had made before it decided that it didn't want to push and it now works fine.

Still do not know what was causing the problem.